# wxPython : Issues on windows using multiple sizers, but works well on linux

Tags: python, wxpython

I am writing a small app that works very well on linux, but I have some trouble on windows. Here is the code sample:

```
import wx
#####################################################################    
class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="StackOverflow",  pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(800,600))
        self.SetMinSize( self.GetSize() )

        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p)

        page1 = AddToCollection(nb)
        page2 = CollectionStatistics(nb)
        nb.AddPage(page1, "Page 1")
        nb.AddPage(page2, "Page 2")

        # finally, put the notebook in a sizer for the panel to manage
        # the layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)
#########################################################################
class CollectionStatistics(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):          

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
#########################################################################
class AddToCollection(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):          

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.v1_qty_list = [str(x) for x in range(9)]
        self.v2_qty_list = [str(x) for x in range(9)]

        self.sizername = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizername.AddGrowableCol(0,0)

        self.name_txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="Enter Name :")
        self.sizername.Add(self.name_txt,(2,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(self,style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER,value=u"")
        self.sizername.Add(self.name,(3,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnPressEnter, self.name)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizername)
        self.SetSizeHints(-1,self.GetSize().y,-1,self.GetSize().y )
##########################################################################
    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.selected_name = self.name.GetValue()
        self.AddToCol()
##########################################################################
    def AddToCol(self):

        self.sizerAdd = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizerAdd.AddGrowableCol(0, 0)

        self.name.Enable(False)

        ### Expansion
        self.expansion = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=['test 1', 'test 2'])
        self.expansion.SetSelection(0)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.expansion,(5,0),(1,6),wx.EXPAND)

        ### Quantities txt
        self.v1_txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="V1 Quantity :")
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.v1_txt,(7,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

        self.v2_txt = wx.StaticText(self, label="V2 Quantity :")
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.v2_txt,(8,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

        ### Quantities choices
        self.v1_qty = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=self.v1_qty_list)
        self.v1_qty.SetSelection(0)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.v1_qty,(7,5),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

        self.v2_qty = wx.Choice(self, -1, choices=self.v1_qty_list)
        self.v2_qty.SetSelection(0)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.v2_qty,(8,5),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)

        ### Ok Button        
        self.Add_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add")
        self.Add_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAdd)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.Add_btn,(9,5),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)        

        ### Reset Button        
        self.Reset_btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Reset")
        self.Reset_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnResetPanel)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.Reset_btn,(9,4),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)             

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerAdd)
        self.SetSizeHints(-1,self.GetSize().y,-1,self.GetSize().y )     
######################################################################
    def OnResetPanel(self,event):
        ### Kill all children
        self.expansion.Destroy()
        self.v1_txt.Destroy()
        self.v1_qty.Destroy()
        self.v2_txt.Destroy()
        self.v2_qty.Destroy()
        self.Add_btn.Destroy()
        self.Reset_btn.Destroy()
        ### Reinitialise sizer
        self.name.Enable(True)
        self.name.SetValue("") 
######################################################################
    def OnAdd(self,event):
        print 'Add'
        self.OnResetPanel(self)
######################################################################
######################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    Main().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Basically, I have a `TextCtrl` in a first sizer which is waiting for an entry. Once the user hits `enter`, several objects appear in a second sizer.

The issue on windows seems to come from the use of the two `gridbagsizers` (`sizername` and `sizerAdd`). After pressing enter (waited event in the `__init__`), the objects defined within the `sizerAdd` do not appear. When I extend the window where the script is running, these objects appear magically !

Any idea ?

**EDIT** : The code is now runnable

Comment: Can you create a small runnable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is these two lines at the end of your `AddToCol` method:

```
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerAdd)
        self.SetSizeHints(-1,self.GetSize().y,-1,self.GetSize().y )
```

At this point, you're changing the sizer of the `AddToCollection` panel from `self.sizername` to `self.sizerAdd`.  The `Enter Name:` label and the textbox however are still within the `self.sizername` sizer.  However, this sizer isn't the sizer for any window, nor has it been added to any other sizer.

Generally, in wxPython, every sizer should be set as the sizer for a window, or be added to another sizer.  This other sizer would then be the sizer for a window, or be contained within another sizer, and so on.  In your case, your `self.sizername` sizer ends up being neither, and in this situation I would expect unpredictable behaviour.  If your code works on Linux then I would say that it happens to work by accident.

I can think of a few things you could do here:

1. Add `self.sizerAdd` as a child of `self.sizername`.  This can be done by replacing the two lines above with

   ```
           self.sizername.Add(self.sizerAdd,(4,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
           self.sizername.Layout()
   ```
2. In `AddToCol`, add the widgets directly to the `self.sizername` sizer instead of adding them to `self.sizerAdd`.
3. Create a `wx.BoxSizer()` with vertical orientation, set that to be the sizer for the `AddToCollection` panel, and add the `self.sizername` and `self.sizerAdd` sizers to your `BoxSizer`.

In all three cases, after creating the new widgets you will need to call the [`Layout()`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html#Layout) method on the top-level sizer, be it either `self.sizername` or the top-level `BoxSizer`.  The code snippet under option 1 includes this line already.

Additionally, you may need to modify your `OnResetPanel()` method.  If you chose options 1 or 3, you will need to remove the `self.sizerAdd` sizer from whichever sizer you added it to.  For example, in option 1, you would add the line

```
        self.sizername.Remove(self.sizerAdd)
```

Another approach would be for your `AddToCol` method to create all the widgets within a Panel and add that to the main panel at the end.  Your `AddToCol` method would then need to create a child panel, add the extra controls as children of this panel instead of the main panel (`self`), set the sizer of the child panel to `self.sizerAdd` and finally add this panel to the `self.sizername` sizer.

```
    def AddToCol(self):

        self.sizerAdd = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        self.sizerAdd.AddGrowableCol(0, 0)

        self.name.Enable(False)

        self.child_panel = wx.Panel(self)

        ### Expansion
        self.expansion = wx.Choice(self.child_panel, -1, choices=['test 1', 'test 2'])
        self.expansion.SetSelection(0)
        self.sizerAdd.Add(self.expansion,(5,0),(1,6),wx.EXPAND)

        # Create other widgets as before but with the parent set to self.child_panel
        # instead of self.

        self.child_panel.SetSizer(self.sizerAdd)
        self.sizername.Add(self.child_panel,(4,0),(1,1),wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizername.Layout()
```

You would then also need to replace the line

```
       self.sizername.Remove(self.sizerAdd)
```

in `OnResetPanel()` with the two lines:

```
       self.sizername.Remove(self.child_panel)
       self.child_panel.Destroy()
```

One thing which bugged me about my approach 1 above was that I saw the widgets briefly appear in the top-left corner before appearing in the correct place.  This adaptation fixes this problem and so makes the GUI behave itself a bit better.  I couldn't reproduce your black area issue you mention in your comment, but hopefully this approach fixes your problem as well.

Comment: I tried quickly option 1 and it works ! Thanks... But, I still have a weird behaviour on windows : when executing the script, a black area appears on the panel.This arera seems to corresponds to the idx (0,0) of the `GridBagSizer`.

Comment: @IpseLium: I couldn't reproduce the black area you mention, but I was seeing the widgets all appear in the top corner before moving to where they should be.  I've come up with another approach that gets rid of this, and have edited my answer to include it.  This might fix your problem as well.  Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not fix the black area issue on the top left corner. Indeed this area seems to be a superposition of all the widgets.

Comment: In fact this black area comes when I add a tab to the notebook. When there is only one tab, all is ok. I edited the main post in this way

Comment: Apparently, this is simply a refresh glitch that can happen on windows. This link talk about this behaviour : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/bdh7xxYMxho. Adding "wx.CallAfter(nb.Refresh)" to the end of
MainFrame.__init__ solves the problem.

Comment: @IpseLium: thanks for finding that link and for letting me know you've solved your problem.